# Selecting many items, which themselves have many items, in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

I have an database representing a book collection. It looks like this:

## books table

```
id    |    title            |    year    |    author_id
--------------------------------------------------------
1       How to Read              1985            7
2       A Dream of Spring        2041            14
3       Tour Guide               2010            40
```

## tags table

```
id    |    tagname
-------------------
1        nonfiction
2        fiction
3        poetry
4        sci-fi
5        magical realism
6        detective
```

## books_tags_links table

```
book    |    tag
------------------
8            4
10           1
10           4
10           5
8            2
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between books and tags: a book can have multiple tags, like 'fiction, detective, sci-fi'.

What I'd like to know is: is it possible for me to select all books, *and* all tags associated with each book, in a single query? I don't know what the result would look like -- a jagged array, I suppose, each book having a different number of tags?

My ultimate aim is to output a HTML table where each row is a book, with the `tr` element having a `data-tag` property for each tag that book's been given, so that I can use JavaScript to hide or show books with some combination of tags. Thus far I can only imagine how to do it by issuing a separate `select tags` query for every book in the list, but that could mean making thousands of database requests, and I want to know if there's a smarter way to do it.

I am using SQLite at the moment, but if there's a solution exclusive to Postgres or MySQL I'd still be interested in learning about it.

Comment: *one-to-many relationship between books and tags* No, it is n to m actually.

Comment: Please put what you've tried and be specific with the problem you're having.  Just about anything is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres you should use `array_agg()` function to aggregate tags linked to a book.

```
select title, array_agg(tagname)
from books b
join books_tags_links l on l.book = b.id
join tags t on l.tag = t.id
group by 1
```

In [SQLite3](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) you have a similar function `group_concat()` (`array_agg()` returns an array, `group_concat()` - a string).

Comment: The `group_concat()` function solves this elegantly for me, and I appreciate knowing about Postgres's nice array features. Thanks for this response!

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, `group_concat()` probably does what you want:

```
select b.*,
       group_concat(t.tagname)
from books b join
     book_tags bt
     on b.id = bt.book join
     tags t
     on bt.tag = t.id
group by b.id;
```

This puts the tags in a comma-separated list, which is probably a good format for your purposes.  You can change the separator with the `SEPARATOR` keyword.